# Xcode 4.1 fatal error: stdlib modified since the precompiled header was built

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors

Building an iPhone app, using:

- Xcode 4.1
- Base SDK iOS 4.3
- Apple LLVM Compiler 2.1

I have started getting the following error:

> fatal error: file
>   '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../lib/clang/2.1/include/stdint.h'
>   has been modified since the precompiled header was built

I have tried reinstalling Xcode and OS X - no luck.  What's causing this?

Comment: See my answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26021850/1528427)

I hope it will help someone :).

Answer (score 152, accepted):

First try a clean build via the Product -> Clean menu (as of XCode 4.6.2).

If that still doesn't work then open the Organizer (from the menu select Window->Organizer). Once the Organizer is open, select Projects from the toolbar at the top of the window. On the left is a list of projects, select the one you are having a problem with.

The details panel (to the right of the list) will display the project name, location, status. The row beneath that shows where the Derived Data is located. Click the Delete... button the far right. A dialog will appear, click Delete.

You can also manually delete the Derived Data:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project name + gobly-gook}
```

This directory contains built products and indexes for the project. It is *OK* to delete it because it only contains items generated by Xcode. Xcode will regenerate everything next time the project is opened.

Comment: Or you can simply "touch" your `.pch` file (or add and remove a char in it) so that it is recompiled, without the need to clean and rebuild all your project (this way the next build is quite faster)

Comment: With older versions of Xcode this was the only way to fix it.

Comment: I had to also delete the Modules/&App dir under DerivedData after I changed a system header (accidentally).

Comment: @AliSoftware when u say touch .pch, that just work because it is just the way to recompile entire project (which can be achieved by recompiling) as .pch is imported to all the class by default, thus touching it make entire project compile all over.

Comment: @rptwsthi That's only true if you have one target and one project in your workspace. I usually have multiple projects, each one having its own `.pch` file; I don't want to "clean" and have **all** my projects (like my Pods) in my workspace recompile. Just changing the `.pch` of my app will only recompile all the files of my app, but **not** the external libraries (like my CocoaPods) and any other projects in my workspace. That's why for this particular issue I prefer to try and touch the `.pch` first, and only clean or remove DerivedData if the two former solutions do not work.

Comment: First just clean Product - Clean

Comment: OSX 10.10.2/Xcode 6.2. I was looking around in NSMutableArray.h for a method, and subsequently when I tried to Build my project, I got that error.  I guess I must have changed something accidentally.  My current project wouldn't build, no old projects would build, and a new project wouldn't build. No amount of cleaning worked for me, and going into the Organizer and deleting didn't work either.  What worked for me was: 1) `$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` 2) Then deleting the whole DerivedData folder: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode$ rm -rf DerivedData`.

Answer (score 76):

I was able to fix it in a much easier way, by simply choosing Product > Clean, then Product > Build from the Xcode menubar.

Comment: +1. Did the same but a "deep clean" by pressing Cmd + Opt + Shft + K

Comment: Please note that you will have to do Clean and Build on each target device that gives you the error. I had to do it for my simulator **and** for my iPad.

Answer (score 37):

Deleting the DerivedData folder did not work for me when Archiving.

I had to look at Build Settings - Build Locations - Precompiled Header Cache Path and delete that folder.

For me that was:

```
/var/folders/_w/t0mj70hd1439tqgxff7_mtt00000gn/C/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders
```

Comment: This folder worked for me too. Although I did previously delete the ~/Library... folder.

Comment: I've just noticed that this folder is in the build settings. It's called Precompiled Header Cache Path!

Answer (score 16):

I thought I would add a separate answer rather than a comment to Cryptognome's answer, because it is in fact a different solution when the issue comes from running `xcodebuild`. Like Cryptognome, I had the error come up with the command-line tool `xcodebuild`. As an alternative to manually going into the `/var` subfolders, I found that I could set my own cache for the shared PCH, which you can do by setting the environment variable  `SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR`, e.g as follows

```
xcodebuild -target Foo -configuration Release SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/tmp/foo/SharedPCH
```

This way, I never get the error in automatic builds.

Note in the above command, I would also typically set the `OBJROOT` and `SYMROOT` env var to build also in /tmp. At the end, I clean things up.

Comment: For me, using `xcodebuild clean build` made the build work again.

Answer (score 4):

The xcodebuild command line tool sometimes fails with this error. This happened to me when I synched an svn workspace to an earlier build. The xcodebuild tool keeps its precompiled headers in the folder Ants mentioned:

```
/var/folders/... scrambled eggs .../-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.503/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/
```

You have to look in the build command itself to see the actual folder name (-include /var/...), but it may be using several if you're building for different architectures (arm6, arm7, simulator, e.g.) So if you're having this problem with a command line build, just delete everything in /var/.../SharedPrecompiledHeaders.

Comment: That was the issue I had as well. Rather than relying on this default cache folder, I set my own cache in the same /tmp subfolder I used for the automatic build, which you can use by passing e.g. `SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/tmp/foo/SharedPrecompiledHeaders` as an argument to `xcodebuild`. This way, I never get the error in automatic builds.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the contents for the Simulator by iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... and hit Rest. This will remove any existing pre-compiled instances of the headers and resources. This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

### Solution:

1)Product->Clean

2)Product->Build

### Error Type:

a kind of Build error

### One of the causes:

one might have changed the framework file.
This sometimes happens when a change is made to a framework that another framework depends upon. The precompiled header cache gets out of sync, and Xcode is unable to compile the given project.

### One of the Scenarios:

one might have chosen Jump To Definition and did some change after selecting a framework control.

Comment: Sure enough, I edited a System header file, which was listed in the error message.  I was able to Time Machine restore the header, then clean and build, with success.

Comment: it's really good solution otherwise one would have to do the aforementioned steps on every project in the system.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of this error simply by cleaning (command+shift+K) and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

I tried above all but no use. Finally I deleted Xcode and re installed again. Now it is working fine..

Xcode->delete->install again

It might help some one...

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on cordova when I ran : `cordova run ios`

```
fatal error: file '/Users/.../cordova/platforms/ios/CordovaLib/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch' has been modified since the precompiled header
  '/var/folders/gb/3cf6hy4x7z3d7hprls6xmd0m0000gr/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0-6A313/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/CordovaLib_Prefix-bfgesbulnxtdepfwgniffeysypgv/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch' was built
note: please rebuild precompiled header
  '/var/folders/gb/3cf6hy4x7z3d7hprls6xmd0m0000gr/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0-6A313/Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/CordovaLib_Prefix-bfgesbulnxtdepfwgniffeysypgv/CordovaLib_Prefix.pch.pch'
1 error generated.

** BUILD FAILED **    

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/NSDictionary+Extensions.o Classes/NSDictionary+Extensions.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    CompileC build/CordovaLib.build/Debug-iphoneos/CordovaLib.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.o Classes/CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

I tried with clean and build but doesn't work, finaly I removed the folder '/var/folders/gb/3cf6hy4x7z3d7hprls6xmd0m0000gr/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/6.0-6A313/Xcode' and works!
This tip, may be help others

Comment: A folder with a path like that seems like a painfully too-narrow example. It might be better to say "I finally removed the offending folder from the error, and it worked."

Comment: Yeap, you are right, but I don't found other case like mine, so I think it can be useful for others

Comment: Exactly my point--if one takes your answer literally they'll wonder "why can't I find this path?" when the thing to take away from this is "I deleted the directory tree containing the precompiled headers (whatever that may be for you) and it worked."

Answer (score 0):

`Clean` ways are not working for me, eventually I solved this issue by reinstall XCode.