# Xcode Won't Compile To Simulator

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors

I've just updated Xcode 4.5 via the App Store, from my previous version which I got from my Apple Developer Account. Since the update I can't compile any apps into the Simulator. I can compile onto a device, e.g. my iPhone.

The error I recieve is

```
    fatal error: file 
    '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/
Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/include/Availability.h'
         has been modified since the precompiled header was built

1 error generated.
```

Comment: try to clean up by  Product > Clean

Comment: Tried it and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: go in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project name + gobly-gook} and delete folder with your project name

Comment: Having this same issue, with another file. Neither cleaning nor deleting the `derived data` has helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13388647/xcode-4-5-2-fatal-error-precompiled-header-has-been-modified

Comment: There is another safe way mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7072227/437146

Answer (score 23, accepted):

go in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{project name + gobly-gook}` and delete folder with your project name.

***EDIT After suggestion***

**NOTE:**

By default Library Folder is hidden so we can't see it.
So we have three way to use this hidden ~/Library folder

1.Unhide Library folder by following command to unhide ~/Library folder

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library
```

Now you can see Library folder as /Users//Library

2. Open GO menu of finder and press Alt key and Library will be visible as new menu item.
   Select that to open Library folder

3. You can access ~/Library folder by Terminal.

Comment: Note that the ~/Library folder is hidden by default. You will have do this via terminal or show hidden files in Finder.

Comment: yap thanks pinkeerach. one other short cut is open Go menu and press Alt. Library will be display as menu item.

Comment: I have `chflags nohidden ~/Library` in my zsh profile. The Library gets hidden every time OS X updates, so this ensures it is always unhidden.

Answer (score 8):

There's easiest way: Just "clean" project (*Product* > *Clean*)

Comment: This works for me when I update to xcode4.6.3. Just try this before you go for the above answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the Organizer (top-right corner of XCode), go to the Projects tab, select your project on the left and then delete the Derived Data.

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I updated Xcode from 6.0.1 to 6.1

I cleaned the project and could compile successfully!!