# Xcode 4.5.2 fatal error: Precompiled header has been modified

Tags: c++, xcode

I've been making changes to my project all day, building and running the project, and now suddenly when trying to build I am now getting this error:

```
fatal error: file
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h'
has been modified since the precompiled header was built
```

- When I attempt to clean the project by going to `Product -> Clean` it refuses to clean and gives me the same error.
- I've removed the `.build` directory from within the project folder, forcing it to rebuild the project and that hasn't fixed anything.
- I've removed the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECT_NAME_HERE` folder, also did not help.
- I've tried closing and reopening Xcode, which also did not help.

I checked the `Foundation.h header` file and it shows a `Date Modified` of Oct. 30th, along with every other file in the `Headers` folder, so it hasn't actually been modified.

Other projects that I build do not have this error.

I'm at a loss here. Seems like Xcode is lying to me.

Comment: Have you changed which OS versions the program is compatible with? I got this error also after fiddling with some OS version numbers somewhere in storyboard settings. I don't remember exactly where

Comment: I haven't. I hadn't changed any settings, I was merely working within the project, making changes, compiling and testing them, and after doing that for a few hours this program just started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't find a clean solution to this problem, but it was a solution nevertheless. The project was under source control, so I submitted my changes to the repository, nuked the entire project off my hard drive, and fetched it back from the repository and that fixed the problem.

My guess is there was somehow a setting in the project or data stored along side the project that is not ever submitted to the repository, which is why deleting and refreshing the project from the repository fixed the issue. What's odd is that deleting `DerivedData` and the `.build` directory from within the project didn't fix the issue, so it would have to be a setting stored elsewhere.

Comment: Cleaning out the cache at this directory worked for me: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

Comment: Great tip @huggie, you saved my day/night! Cleaning the cache worked like a charm for me as well!

Comment: clean ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YourProjectDir/ and clean ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache solves my problem.