# Availability.h file not found - Xcode 4.6.1 - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

After I updated XCode to 4.6.1 version, when I open a project developed in the last Xcode version, it gives me an error when I run the application, on the `#import <Availability.h>` (I don't know in which class is that code line). The error I get is: "'Availability.h' file not found". How can I solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524771/xcode-wont-compile-to-simulator

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be with the `Foundation.framework`, try to delete the framework in build-phases and add it again to your project.
Once you have added it again, just clean and build your project, it will solve your problem.

If by doing the above does not solve your problem then you will have to re-install xcode I am afraid.

Comment: I just did that, but it is still not working. Do you know what else can I do?

Comment: How did you installed XCode? try to update via Xcode and remove any old references of xcode if you have manually installed.

Answer (score 0):

at Target->Build Phases-=>Link Binary with Libraries remove Foundation.Framework and add it again

Comment: I just did, and it is still not working, do you know what else can i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380186/availability-h-uikit-h-etc-not-found check this address all possible reasons are here