# xcode5: Apple LLVM 5.1 error when building

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

If I'll run my app on the iOS-Simulator this error comes up:

```
fatal error: file '/Users/Patti/Desktop/Picxxr/Picxxr/Picxxr-Prefix.pch' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/Patti/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Picxxr-gcakojkodoomqcertyparosqruxs/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Picxxr-Prefix-dpxcuqgwybsqepgyjnhyqvzeyjhk/Picxxr-Prefix.pch.pch' was built
```

Does somebody knows why?

Comment: Are suggestions in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793329/fixing-file-project-pch-has-been-modified-since-the-precompiled-header-was-bui) not working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have altered your precompiled header file in some way. This file lists global `#import` sand `#define` s to be included in all files in your project - usually used for importing `UIKit` and `Foundation`, though you can add other stuff. Since this makes all the files in your project out of date, it means you need to clean the derived data folder (Option Apple+Shift -> K), then rebuild the project - this will regenerate the whole project and should fix the problem.