# Unable to build app that use cocoa pods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I recently reinstalled my Mac OS X Maverick distro and setted up my development environment. I was trying to follow the following tutorial to learn more about cocoa pods
 and I never could get the build to run successfully.

The tutorial is from this source: http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2

To resume, I've followed the next steps on terminal app:

1- run: sudo gem update --system (OK)

2- run: sudo gem install cocoapods (OK)

3- run: pod setup (OK - terminal returned this "Setting up CocoaPods master repo
Setup completed (read-only access)")

4- on the app path run: pod init (created Podfile)

5- run: open -a Xcode Podfile (modified iOS version OK and added pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1' between the "target 'Showtracker' do)

6- run: pod install (everything worked fine and the workspace and all files were created correctly)

After that I've opened the workspace file from finder and the workspace in Xcode showed exactly as it should with the 2 project files

When I've tried to build the app I've got the following error as the build result:

> CompileC
>   /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
>   AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.m normal i386
>   objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods
>       export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
>   -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -iquote /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -iquote /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -I/Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/BuildHeaders -I/Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/BuildHeaders/AFNetworking
>   -I/Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/Headers -I/Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/Headers/AFNetworking
>   -I/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -I/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -fobjc-arc -w -Xanalyzer -analyzer-disable-checker -include /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-prefix-aypnknzjycfqnmhhpckrwqzjddtp/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.dia
>   -c /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.m
>   -o /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
>
> Stack dump:
>   0.    Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -cc1 -triple i386-apple-ios7.0.0 -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name AFHTTPRequestOperation.m -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -target-cpu yonah -target-linker-version 236.3 -gdwarf-2 -coverage-file /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
>   -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1
>   -dependency-file /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.d
>   -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk
>   -iquote /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-project-headers.hmap -include-pch /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-prefix-aypnknzjycfqnmhhpckrwqzjddtp/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-prefix.pch.pch
>   -D DEBUG=1 -D COCOAPODS=1 -I /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -I /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -I /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -I /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/BuildHeaders -I /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/BuildHeaders/AFNetworking
>   -I /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/Headers -I /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/Headers/AFNetworking
>   -I /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/DerivedSources/i386
>   -I /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -O0 -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -w -std=gnu99 -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods -ferror-limit 19
>   -fmacro-backtrace-limit 0 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -fobjc-runtime=ios-7.0.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fobjc-arc -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fasm-blocks -vectorize-slp -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.dia
>   -o /Users/mtopp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShowTracker-eidspshbmfufcxeoawmixoxklvzq/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-ShowTracker-AFNetworking.build/Objects-normal/i386/AFHTTPRequestOperation.o
>   -x objective-c /Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.m
>
> 1. parser at end of file
> 2. Code generation
> 3. Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/mtopp/Documents/Workspace/ShowTracker/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.m'.
> 4. Running pass 'X86 DAG->DAG Instruction Selection' on function '@"\01-[AFHTTPRequestOperation responseObject]"' clang: error: unable
>      to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11 clang: error: clang
>      frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation) Apple
>      LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) Target:
>      i386-apple-darwin13.0.0 Thread model: posix clang: note: diagnostic
>      msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to
>      http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash
>      backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script. clang:
>      note: diagnostic msg:
>
>    ---
>
> PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT: Preprocessed
>   source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at: clang: note:
>   diagnostic msg:
>   /var/folders/z3/wmz14g7527l40snggf1b5qb40000gn/T/AFHTTPRequestOperation-4de2a1.m
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg:
>   /var/folders/z3/wmz14g7527l40snggf1b5qb40000gn/T/AFHTTPRequestOperation-4de2a1.sh
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg:
>
> ******************** Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 254

I can't find the solution and the error is so general that I've read a lot of different problems.

I will appreciate any help or guidance you can provide

Comment: What version is the compiler?

Comment: I'm using latest Xcode version 5.1.1

Comment: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793329/fixing-file-project-pch-has-been-modified-since-the-precompiled-header-was-bui

Comment: same name variables with same type, in two different M files. mostly causes this issue.