# "Foundation/foundation.h" not found error with Theos

Tags: ios, theos

I get an error like this when i am trying to compile my tweak. What should i do?

```
/var/theos/Prefix.pch:9:11: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h'
      file not found
                #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
                        ^
```

Comment: remove that line and Import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

Comment: @KKRocks Which line? The whole quoted text is an error, i didnt write anything about this. Just write "make this package install" and it gives this error after some proccess

Comment: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h> this line.

Comment: @KKRocks how? This is an error message :/

Comment: check in build phase -> Link Binary With Libraries. if there framework exist then remove that.

Comment: @KKRocks I linked "perl" /usr/bin to /usr/locale/bin, is this what you saying? Sorry for all idiotic questions, i am trying to learn. Thanks for patience!!

Comment: did any .pch file exist in you project. find that file and check there .

Comment: @KKRocks no it doesnt have any .pch file. I started it as "iphone - tweak" option. It only has these -> control, makefile, xxx.plist, xxx.xm, and obj folder

Comment: see this may help you -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793329/fixing-file-project-pch-has-been-modified-since-the-precompiled-header-was-bui

Comment: @KKRocks sorry but this isnt similar with my error. Mine is this https://imgur.com/gallery/MalGH