# file has been modified since the precompiled header was built

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

So I accidentally modified a header (`CBCentralManager.h)` and caused the above error to show when I build. I searched stack overflow for the solution, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072227/797767). Even after deleting the derived data, I still get the same error. I've also tried to delete the `ModuleCache/FUW5IOHP9BIS` folder with no success.

Here is the specific error I'm seeing:

`file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Headers/CBCentralManager.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/var/folders/pj/hslm53_51xxd_npfqym5r6z00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/ModuleCache/FUW5IOHP9BIS/CoreBluetooth.pcm was built`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried clean and rebuild from xcode's menu?

Comment: Yes, I've tried everything in the link in the question. It doesn't make sense that clearing the derived data does not fix this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793329/fixing-file-project-pch-has-been-modified-since-the-precompiled-header-was-bui

Comment: Try this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/25843228/2557910

Worked fine for me.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode and restarting Xcode fixed this for me (Xcode 6 B7). Suspect an aggressive caching bug. **Warning! This deletes archives from all your projects.**

No amount of cleaning / build folder cleaning / derived data deleting helped before that.

Comment: I'll switch your answer to the correct one (since I can no longer reproduce the issue, and several people verified that your solution works).

Comment: CAREFUL! This will also wipe out all your archives from all your projects!

Comment: Instead try deleting `/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache`. That solves the purpose.

Comment: please, could you explain to me what implicates, in practice, the warning?

Answer (score 90):

I faced this issue on OS10.10 with Xcode 6. I resolved issue by removing .pcm files.

To delete press 'shift+command+g' & delete all .pcm files or goto the folder ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/ & delete all .pcm files.

Perform deep clean by pressing 'shift+alt+command+k.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thank you for explaining where they are and the environment you were in.

Comment: Deleting the whole ModuleCache folder worked for me with Xcode6

Comment: OSX 10.10.2/Xcode 6.2. 1) There are no .pcm files listed anywhere in my project. 2) Pressing shift+command+g in Xcode does nothing except make a bonk! sound. 3) There are no .pcm files in the directory ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/

Comment: None of my old projects will build, and a new project won't build either. Wow, Xcode6 is a super IDE!

Comment: @7stud I have not started using XCode6.2.x. Might be possible that Apple made some changes in Xcode IDE.

Comment: What worked for me was doing what @Laith suggested: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode$ rm -rf DerivedData`.

Comment: Cool，it is good way to clean pem files. Awesome. Thanks

Comment: Deleting ModuleCache also worked in 2023 with Xcode 14.3 

Answer (score 24):

Remove the pcm file

> rm
>   "/var/folders/pj/hslm53_51xxd_npfqym5r6z00000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/5.0-5A1412/Xcode/ModuleCache/FUW5IOHP9BIS/CoreBluetooth.pcm"

then

> Clean Project( Cmd+Shift+K)

**Problem solved**

Comment: I've tried deleting the whole ModuleCache folder with no success (see question). Unless you're implying that deleting just the CoreBluetooth.pcm will fix the problem.

Comment: for my case, i just need to delete pcm file then clean and it worked :)

Comment: @Mark: ya, i meant so, because in the most of my cases i always try like this first. :D

Comment: the solution for me with my Jenkins build was to add rm -Rf $TMPDIR../C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/*/Xcode/*/Xcode/SharedPrecompileHeaders/

Answer (score 5):

Just select clean from the project menu. That should force a complete rebuild and solve the rproblem.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. Clean did not fix the issue, nor did build folder clean. Neither did deleting the derived data folder.

Comment: @Mark, sounds like an Xcode bug. I would suggest submitting an Apple Radar bug.

Comment: Will do. I'll link the radar bug in the original question once I've submitted it.

Answer (score 4):

Try going to your Organizer -> Projects, and you'll see the path for where you're derived data is saved. Mine looks something like "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[Project name]-[mumbo jump]"

Delete the "[Project name]-[mumbo jump]" folder, and you should be all good.

Comment: This is what the link in my question suggested, and it is the first thing I tried. It does not fix my issue, as the error is thrown again.

Comment: The important part for me was to find where my derived data is and cleaning that, rather than assuming it's in ~/Library/.  Mine is at ~/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData so I cleaned that and the ModuleCache and that fixed it

Answer (score 4):

Deep clean (Cmd + Opt + Shft + K), clearing folder DerivedData, clearing simulator, restarting Xcode and mac doesn't work for me.

Problem was fixed only after changing pch-file (adding a whitespace or comment/uncomment some code). File was incorrectly cached on build phase by Xcode. Changing this file fixed problem.

Answer (score 4):

Manually deleting the DerivedData folder fixed it for me.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me too.  Thanks!  `$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/` then `~/Library/Developer/Xcode$ rm -rf DerivedData`.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems the only way to fix this issue is to uninstall Xcode and download it again. This fixed my problem.

Comment: I agree it's very strange. There's probably something going on that we've missed. An uninstall just happens to reset it.

Comment: Slightly less extreme - deleting ~/Library/Developer/Xcode worked in my case (no amount of cleaning did).

Comment: Good to know there's alternatives to uninstalling Xcode.

Comment: Better yet, delete just ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/ModuleCache. That way you don't lose all the other data.

Answer (score 2):

quit xcode and reopen it .This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue. Deleting moduleCache and restarting Xcode & Mac did not help me to resolve the issue.

Solution that worked for me: I copied the path "/private/var/folders/5s/1q3qz48j6zxc028txvdyqhwr000btt/C/org.llvm.clang/ModuleCache" in Finder->Go to folder, deleted all the folders from that ModuleCache.

Now I am able to build successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try these, clean and then build again

```
find /var/folders 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' | grep '\.pcm' | xargs rm
find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData 2>&1 | grep -v 'Permission denied' | grep '\.pcm' | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing above works for me, even uninstalling Xcode. Finally, I tried copying the modified file from other project to my current project, this worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the precompiled ~/Library/Developer/Xcode and restarting Xcode, plus a few of the other ideas presented here, nothing was working. As it seems to be a multiple-target kind of issue, I found after changing the target to another target, building/uploading the other target successfully, then changing back (after doing the other things) to the target I was looking to build / upload originally, I was finally successful.