# Xcode 6 works in pyshical iPhone but not in the simulator - Cocoa Pods files errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode6

I've just installed XCode 6 and something odd is happening.

I can run my app in a physical iOS7 phone, but not in the simulator, so that means the app is working fine.

When I build in the simulator I get this error:

file '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/usr/include/sysexits.h' has been modified since the precompiled header '/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-bssuvokuewryahcpprljeeteqzui/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Pods-xxxxx-Mantle-prefix-eoukyqdtliihgbfojcbqetlttnwe/Pods-xxxxx-Mantle-prefix.pch.pch' was built

I tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Removing the derived data folder
- Uninstall cocoa pods in that project following this: [How to remove CocoaPods from a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427421/how-to-remove-cocoapods-from-a-project)

I think it's just related with the simulator but I don't know what I can do. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, this solution worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391768/file-has-been-modified-since-the-precompiled-header-was-built/25182895#comment40550716_25182895

Comment: @Matz this is the solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25182895/624920  It's similar, but more generic.

Comment: That is the same, which I've posted :D